# sp_OAMethod 'OpenTextFile' clarification

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I can seem to find an answer to this even on Microsoft sites I am using this:

```
EXECUTE @RetCode = sp_OAMethod @FileSystem, 
 'OpenTextFile',
 @FileHandle OUTPUT,
 @FilePath,
 8,
 1
```

I would like to know what the finale int parameter (1) does and what other options there are for this. I experimented and used 2 but did not see any difference.

I know that the second last int parameter (8) specifies an append vs using 2 a write but do not know of other values for this parameter either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The sp_OAMethod is executing method of the given object, in this case is a FileSystemObject 
OpenTextFile has 4 parameters in this order:

> 1. **FilePath** -*Required*. The name of the file to open
> 2. **Mode** - *Optional*. How to open the file
>
>    - 1 = Reading - Open a file for reading. You cannot write to this file.
>    - 2 = Writing - Open a file for writing.
>    - 8 = Appending - Open a file and write to the end of the file.
> 3. **Create** - *Optional*. Sets whether a new file can be created if the filename does not exist. True indicates that a new file can be created, and False indicates that a new file will not be created. False is default.
> 4. **Format** - *Optional*. The format of the file
>
>    - 0 = TristateFalse - Open the file as ASCII. This is default.
>    - 1 = TristateTrue - Open the file as Unicode.
>    - 2 = TristateUseDefault - Open the file using the system default.

In your case (8) is the `Mode`, and (1) is the `Create`.
You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_opentextfile.asp).

Comment: Thank you very much for that breakdown and providing the additional info via link.

Comment: Note that the file format parameters should be NEGATIVE. See the documentation. And I verified they should be negative on SQL Server 2014.